# Windows Tasklist.exe continuously popup while checking TaskList in subprocess

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, subprocess, windows-security

I have developed windows application to monitor the current running process and it will scan the running task list via **subprocess**  in defined interval and application running smoothly on IDE but after compiling and execute exe, then it will popup **C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\TASKLIST.exe** terminal each time when scan the task list.
I am highly appreciate your expert supports to avoid this glitch
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKkN2.png)

```
import subprocess
from time import sleep

def check_process_running(self):
    process_name = b'CUSTOM_APP.exe'
    get_tasklist = 'TASKLIST'
    tasklist = subprocess.check_output(get_tasklist)
    proc_data = [row for row in tasklist.split(b'\n') if row.startswith(process_name)]
    
  
def events_tracker(self):
 
    while True:
        try:
          tasks = self.check_process_running()
          # some calculations 
        except Exception as e:
          logger.exception("event capture triggered exception "+str(e))

      time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Show the relevant code properly formatted in the question. If possible, create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

When you have built python application (without console) on windows there are missing `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` in the process which cause creation of new console (I think it's because of logic in `subprocess` module). To avoid this on windows you can create detached process by passing `creationflags`.

This should work:

```
import subprocess


def check_process_running(process_name):
    tasklist = subprocess.check_output(
        ["TASKLIST.exe"],
        creationflags=(
            subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
            | subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS
        )
    )
    return [
        row.strip()
        for row in tasklist.decode().split("\n")
        if row.startswith(process_name)
    ]
```